# Uncaught reference error:$ is not defined simple script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to learn JavaScript and jQuery however I got stuck at this point.

This is my script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
              $("#right").click(function(){
                    $("#seccion1").fadeout("normal",function(){
                                           $("#seccion2").fadeIn("normal");
                        });
                                
                                
                });

              
              });
```

I've called it from here http://www.ingen.com.co/HTML5/sitio.html with this line of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

and I keep getting the same error. Please help!

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but are you including the jQuery JavaScript file?

Comment: The `$` function is from the jQuery library. You need to add `<script></script>` tags including jQuery. http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments above, you need to load jQuery by adding this code before any other `<script>` blocks:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```